# How to sort JsonArray based on multiple values in java?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a `JsonArray` which has enormous amount of "id" and "Genre" which will be random.The sample json array is below:

```
{
    "category": [
        { "Id":"23" , "Genre":"English News" }, 
        { "Id":"43" , "Genre":"Entertainment" }, 
        { "Id":"255" , "Genre":"Music" },
        { "Id":"553" , "Genre":"Games" },
        { "Id":"97" , "Genre":"regional" } 
     ]
}
```

I need this `jsonarray` to get sorted based on:

(1.Music
2.Games
3.Regional
4.English news
5.Entertainment) this order.

How to get this json array sorted? Is there any third party lib to use?

Any help would be appreciated:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create multiple Comparators and can use any of the comparator while sorting.

```
  public class ComparatorsGroup {
                public static Comparator<Item> IdComparator = new Comparator<Item>() {
                  public int compare(Item item1, Item item2) {
                     return item1.getId().compareTo(item2.getId());
                  }
            };

            public static Comparator<Item> GenreComparator = new Comparator<Item>() {
                  public int compare(Item item1, Item item2) {
                     return item1.getGenre().compareTo(item2.getGenre());
                  }
            };
}
```

While calling the sort method you can pass any of the comparator based on the sort required.

```
 Collections.sort(myList, ComparatorsGroup.GenreComparator);
```

For more details you can have a look to the below example by MkYong.

[Java object sorting example (Comparable and Comparator)](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write multiple comparators here i.e a comparator for each field you want to sort on and then chain those comparator in a sequence that you want. Pass these list of comparators to base compartor where in compare method you will loop on these comparators and call their compare method. Something like below:

[Pseduo Code]

```
public class BaseComparator implements
            Comparator<Map<String, String>> {

        public List<Comparator<Map<String, String>>> listComparators;

        public BaseComparator(
                List<Comparator<Map<String, String>>> comparators) {
            this.listComparators = comparators;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(Map<String, String> obj1, Map<String, String> obj2) {
            for (Comparator<Map<String, String>> comparator : listComparators) {
                int result = comparator.compare(obj1, obj2);
                if (result != 0) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

Collections.sort(list,
                OpportunitySorter.getBaseComparator(SortDefinition));
```

Answer (score 0):

For ease of use , i have used Jackson and i am running JDK-8. This is a working revision of code.
Dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>


import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonSorter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //1.Music 2.Games 3.Regional 4.English news 5.Entertainment
        final Map<String, Integer> customSort = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        customSort.put("Music", new Integer(1));
        customSort.put("Games", new Integer(2));
        customSort.put("Regional", new Integer(3));
        customSort.put("English news", new Integer(4));
        customSort.put("Entertainment", new Integer(5));

        String jsonString = "{\"category\": [{ \"Id\":\"23\" , \"Genre\":\"English News\" },{ \"Id\":\"43\" , \"Genre\":\"Entertainment\" },{ \"Id\":\"255\" , \"Genre\":\"Music\" },{ \"Id\":\"553\" , \"Genre\":\"Games\" },{ \"Id\":\"97\" , \"Genre\":\"regional\" }]}"; // Load this in whatever way makes sense for you
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> parsedJson = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Map.class);
        List<Map<String, String>> genres = (List) parsedJson.get("category");
        genres.stream().sorted((thisMap, thatMap) -> customSort.get(thisMap.get("Genre")).compareTo(customSort.get(thatMap.get("Genre"))));
        genres.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```